# How to stop scrolling

Tags: javascript, scroll

How can I prevent the page from sliding? Let say:

```js
let timeout = 0;
document.onmousewheel = () => {
 window.clearTimeout(timeout);
 timeout = setTimeout(() => {
  console.log("Stop scrolling");
 }, 20);
}
document.onscroll = () => {
 console.log("scrolling");
}
```

```css
p {
 height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<p> Sample </p><p> Sample </p><p> Sample </p><p> Sample </p><p> Sample </p><p> Sample </p><p> Sample </p><p> Sample </p><p> Sample </p><p> Sample </p><p> Sample </p><p> Sample </p><p> Sample </p>
```

The idea here is that while I am not rolling the wheel of the mouse, it should not be scrolling. Sometimes if you do it too fast it continues scrolling for a while.
 How can I prevent this?

Using `-webkit-overflow-scrolling`:

```js
let timeout = 0;
document.onmousewheel = () => {
 window.clearTimeout(timeout);
 timeout = setTimeout(() => {
  console.log("Stop scrolling");
 }, 20);
}
document.onscroll = () => {
 console.log("scrolling");
}
```

```css
p {
 height: 300px;
}
body {
 -webkit-overflow-scrolling: auto;
}
```

```html
<p> Sample </p><p> Sample </p><p> Sample </p><p> Sample </p><p> Sample </p><p> Sample </p><p> Sample </p><p> Sample </p><p> Sample </p><p> Sample </p><p> Sample </p><p> Sample </p><p> Sample </p>
```

It is not working as I expected, maybe I'm using it wrong?

Comment: Depends on the mousewheel you have. If you have the mousewheel that clicks as it rolls then you won't have this issue at all. If your mousewheel does not have the clicks then you will see this because your browser registers all of the scrolling you are doing and since it does not click/stop over scrolling that's why you see the "after scrolling"

Comment: @Huangism yes, that is what I want to prevent. I need at any time to be able to stop the "after scrolling".

Comment: I would think you can just preventDefault but I can't really test because I don't have the non clicking mouse

Comment: LOL guys it works, you just didn't notice that this code is wrong, it writes stop scrolling when you start doing it!

Comment: @MarcoSalerno thats what Im trying, when it says "stop" it should stop and not print "scrollin" :)

Comment: It doesn't make sense, you want scroll while blocking it?

Comment: @MarcoSalerno I want to block the "after scroll" that happens when I roll the mouse wheel too fast, and it continues scrolling the page about a second

Comment: I give up you don't understand

Comment: @Marco the code was not wrong, just incomplete. Sometimes I first get "scrolling" and other times "stop scrolling". It's probably a timing thing. Anyway, return false based on a flag seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with css

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-overflow-scrolling

Just add property `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: auto` to your `body`.

Comment: Nothing to indicate here that this is aimed at a -webkit browser

Answer (score 0):

I can't really test this, but does return false on the scroll event prevent the scroll?

```js
var timeout = 0, doScroll;
document.onmousewheel = function() {
 doScroll = 1;
 window.clearTimeout(timeout);
 timeout = setTimeout( function() {
  console.log("Stop scrolling");
  doScroll = 0;
 }, 20);
}
document.onscroll = function() {
 if (doScroll == 0) return false;
 console.log("scrolling");
}
```

```css
p {
 height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<p> Sample </p><p> Sample </p><p> Sample </p><p> Sample </p><p> Sample </p><p> Sample </p><p> Sample </p><p> Sample </p><p> Sample </p><p> Sample </p><p> Sample </p><p> Sample </p><p> Sample </p>
```

Comment: Good to see it's working. Just be aware that the logic as is also blocks scrolling for any other code that may wish to trigger scroll.